# ActiveX Calendar Control Not Working In Windows 7

Tags: html, windows-7, asp-classic, compatibility

We have a classic ASP application that uses the following calendar object:

```
<HTML>
<BODY bgcolor="lightgrey">
<OBJECT id=Calendar1 style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" 
    classid="clsid:8E27C92B-1264-101C-8A2F-040224009C02" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="_Version" VALUE="524288">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="7620">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="5080">
    <PARAM NAME="_StockProps" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="BackColor" VALUE="-2147483633">
    <PARAM NAME="Year" VALUE="2002">
    <PARAM NAME="Month" VALUE="10">
    <PARAM NAME="Day" VALUE="29">
    <PARAM NAME="DayLength" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="MonthLength" VALUE="2">
    <PARAM NAME="DayFontColor" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="FirstDay" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="GridCellEffect" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="GridFontColor" VALUE="10485760">
    <PARAM NAME="GridLinesColor" VALUE="-2147483632">
    <PARAM NAME="ShowDateSelectors" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="ShowDays" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="ShowHorizontalGrid" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="ShowTitle" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="ShowVerticalGrid" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="TitleFontColor" VALUE="10485760">
    <PARAM NAME="ValueIsNull" VALUE="0"></OBJECT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This works fine on a Windows XP Machine using IE7/8.  However, this does NOT work on a Windows 7 machine using IE8.  Is this an OS issue and my calendar object needs to be updated or something else entirely?  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the office versions in both computers? Windows 7 is x64 or x86?

Comment: @Eugene For Xp/7 its Office 2003/2007 respectively. Windows 7 is x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the jQuery DatePicker instead. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Thanks for your time everyone!

Answer (score 0):

We installed Office 2003 on the browser machine and hey presto everything came back to life.