# Calendar Control do not load on IE 9 - ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using the below code for calendar control which returns the selected date to a text field. This was working just fine for browsers below IE 8 but not IE 9. Can someone please provide some insight to fix this calendar control to be working in IE 9 or 10.

F12 Developer Tools Console Message:

> HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks

Also:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'document.all.calendar1.value'

```
<head>

<title>SELECT A DATE</title>

<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />-->

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

</head>

<BODY bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 rightMargin=0 bgcolor=#cccac0>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT>

      Sub window_onunload

            window.returnvalue = formatdatetime(document.all.Calendar1.value,2)

      end sub

</SCRIPT>

<!--<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT>

      Sub window_onunload

            window.returnvalue = formatdatetime(document.getElementById("Calendar1"))

      end sub

</SCRIPT>-->

<OBJECT id="Calendar1" style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 289px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 198px"

classid="clsid:8E27C92B-1264-101C-8A2F-040224009C02" width=289 height=198 VIEWASTEXT class="Calendar">

<PARAM NAME="_Version" VALUE="524288">

<PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="7646">

<PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="5239">

<PARAM NAME="_StockProps" VALUE="1">

<PARAM NAME="BackColor" VALUE="-2147483633">

<PARAM NAME="Year" VALUE="<%=year(now())%>">

<PARAM NAME="Month" VALUE="<%=month(now())%>">

<PARAM NAME="Day" VALUE="<%=day(now())%>">

<PARAM NAME="DayLength" VALUE="1">

<PARAM NAME="MonthLength" VALUE="2">

<PARAM NAME="DayFontColor" VALUE="0">

<PARAM NAME="FirstDay" VALUE="1">

<PARAM NAME="GridCellEffect" VALUE="1">

<PARAM NAME="GridFontColor" VALUE="10485760">

<PARAM NAME="GridLinesColor" VALUE="-2147483632">

<PARAM NAME="ShowDateSelectors" VALUE="-1">

<PARAM NAME="ShowDays" VALUE="-1">

<PARAM NAME="ShowHorizontalGrid" VALUE="-1">

<PARAM NAME="ShowTitle" VALUE="-1">

<PARAM NAME="ShowVerticalGrid" VALUE="-1">

<PARAM NAME="TitleFontColor" VALUE="10485760">

<PARAM NAME="ValueIsNull" VALUE="0">

</OBJECT>

<BR>

<center><!-- <INPUT type=button value="Select Date" onClick=window.close></center> -->

<img src="selectadate.png" alt="Select a Date" onClick=window.close>

</BODY>
```

Comment: You've tagged this as javascript and classic asp.  As far as I can see it uses neither, it's a question about client side vbscript. I take it that you're aware this won't work on non IE browsers

Comment: Your also using `ActiveX` controls which is another IE proprietary technology.

Comment: I would check your ActiveX control security settings as my guess would be it's being blocked by IE because it's not trusted in the current security zone. If the site is trusted (by you) try adding it to the Trust Sites security zone and testing your page again.

Comment: John, I do realise this do not work on non IE browsers. @Lankymart- I have tried with active x too, but no luck. There is a textbox with calendar control image pop up which calls this calendar.asp page throughout the application. Is there a way, I can ignore this and create a new calendar control without disturbing any other asp pages in the application?

Comment: @user3581928 just google it and you will find gazillion examples for calendar using simple JavaScript, Ajax, jQuery etc. And most important those examples will be browser independent. http://www.ajaxshake.com/en/JS/1151/calendars.html or http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/Calendars/list_test.asp and much more...

Comment: @user3581928 Did you check the `ActiveX` security settings?, in more recent browsers the defaults have become far more restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
document.all
```

with

```
document.forms[0]
```

if you have just one form in the script

Comment: VBScript arrays are used as such: `document.forms(0)`

Comment: What @Rich says is true also `document.forms(0)` would not make a difference because there is no form in the page. The issue is not with your `document.all`. I see you've tried `document.getElementById()` does this also error?

Comment: @Dalibor -  thank you, but it didnot help probably bcoz Lankymart said , since there is no form in this page. Also, i got an error with document.getelementbyid()

Comment: Please find below URL, this is exactly what I am using in my page.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947884/activex-calendar-control-not-working-in-windows-7